# How to display same values in set of columns once sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a sql query result like this

```
id | subId |  code |  name  |      response
1  |     1 |   abc |    xyz |     "Whatever"
1  |     1 |   abc |    xyz |     "Whatever2"
1  |     2 |   def |    qrt |     "Whatever3"
1  |     2 |   def |    qrt |     "Whatever4"
```

I need to show first four columns(id,subid,code,name) once(on the basis of id and subid) where as response ids and response values as it is like

```
id | subId |  code |  name  |    responsevalue
1  |     1 |   abc |    xyz |     "Whatever"
                            |     "Whatever2"
1  |     2 |   def |    qrt |     "Whatever3"
                            |     "Whatever4"
```

Comment: you could group concatenate the results, but I guess it kinda depends on how you are displaying this data

Comment: Which DB do you use ? (MSSQL,MySQL,Oracle,....). Please add a tag.

Comment: This type of transformation is usually done at the application layer.  It *can* be done in the database but it is really for presentation.

Comment: is responseid unique for every record?

Comment: Chaos Legion Please recheck the question I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER() to get a row number of record in the group and then for all not first records (row number <> 1) output NULLs with CASE statement.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
   SELECT T.*,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY responseid ) as rn
   FROM T
)

SELECT 
   CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN ID ELSE NULL END as ID,
   CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN SubId ELSE NULL END as SubID,
   CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN Code ELSE NULL END as Code,
   CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN Name ELSE NULL END as Name,
   responseId,
   response_value
FROM T1
ORDER BY T1.id,rn
```

Comment: vatex question is slightly changed,sorry but that question actually created a confusion that response id is unique or not, actually the scenario is somewhat like this what i have edited

Comment: vatex actually your solution is working for me except that T1 and T are same tables and both are obtained from a series of joins